# Wordpress Front page and Post Page are displaying the the same content

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am working on a basic Wordpress website and wanted the home page to be a custom static page, so I have created a page called `home.php` and and page called `news.php` and then in the WP admin I've gone to: `Setting` then `Reading` selected the `a static page` option, selected the `Front Page` as Home and then the `Posts Page` as News.

However when Ive gone to view the site in the browser both pages display the same content.. allthough the URL DOES change to what ever the page is ie: `localhost:8888/mysite/home or localhost:8888/mysite/news`

I'm not sure if i'm missing something really simple.. but I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong?

My Code for the home page is:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Home Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">

<h1>This is the homepage</h1>

</div>    

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and then my code for the News page is:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: News Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header();  ?>

<div class="container">

 <h2>This is the Blog page</h2>        

        <?php $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'orderby' => 'date',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'posts_per_page' => 4,
                                'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                                'post_parent' => $parent
                            ); ?>
                      <?php query_posts($args); ?>

                      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                          <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                              <article>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
    <time><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></time>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>   
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
 </article>


                          <?php endwhile; ?>
                      <?php endif; ?>  
    <?php get_footer();  ?>
  </div>
```

If anyone could help me try to figure out where I am going wrong, it would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Use index.php as home page and single.php as post page.

Comment: `page-home.php` instead of `home.php` and `page-news.php` instead of `news.php`. Those are the names you need to use, inside your active theme folder. The syntax is `page-<slug of the page>`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should probably be moved to the [WordPress area](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

What are your files named in your theme? WordPress uses a hierarchy to determine which template to use when building a page. You can [read more about that in the codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)

For your purposes, it sounds like you need to name your home page template 'front-page.php' and your news page 'home.php'

**Note:** This is only if you're creating a theme. If you're modifying a theme, its better to give your page templates names like so: 'page-news.php' and 'page-home.php'. [See this answer for more details.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23473235/2381695)

Answer (score 1):

Posting with full details.

First, make sure your `.php` files are inside the active theme folder.
(eg: `/wp-content/themes/<themename>/`).

Create 2 static pages within wordpress first:

`Pages -> Add New -> Home`

`Pages -> Add New -> News`

You can enter any title for the page, but make sure they have the slugs `home` and `news`.

Now, the reading settings. Settings > Reading:

Front page displays: (x) A static page

```
 Front Page: <choose **home** which you created earlier>

 Posts Page: <choose **news** which you created earlier>
```

Now, for the custom homepage, name your php file `page-home.php` and for news, `page-news.php`. Place them inside your active theme folder.